# Combine multiple excel CSV documents into one, slightly different formatted sheet

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

I have several CSV files which can be combined into one using the code below:

```bash
@echo off
copy *.csv Union.csv
```

I would like to combine the CSV files into one, but have the columns slightly different. As a template I use uses a slightly different column format. I want to combine the original CSVs into one format file, use for import into Unleashed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach for this problem is to write a transformer that normalizes the structures.  You can easily accomplish this task using ... well, nearly any proper (note: not bash/zsh/powershell/bat) programming language.

The typical approach would be to read each file, translate the headers (and data if necessary) to a unified format, and write the data out to a normalized CSV file.

This is the bread and butter of any number of programming 101 classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking to do this with Python - is it possible to copy csv data and paste it into another formatted CSV?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  And, it's not even that hard.  Mostly, you just need to spend some time looking at the CSV libraries for your language of choice.  Luckily, Python has one built in.